# Delete Column in Excel using VBA if number in row ends in '00'

Tags: excel, vba

Sample below.

I need to delete all rows on a worksheet where the number column doesn't end in 00

```
user_id Number
john    098746700
Matt    087788888
mary    098888700
```

Expected result

```
user_id Number
john    098746700
mary    098888700
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run from end to beginning
2. Check if the value ends with '00' (if a string, check last two digits. If an integer, check that mod(value,100) = 0).
3. Whatever_Range_You_Are_Using.`EntireRow.Delete`

Have fun